# How to make sure there is always 2 decimal places after a number is divided?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know how to make it so that when I divide something like `5 / 2`, it doesn't just have 1 decimal place after it, for example instead of the answer that it would provide which would be `2.5`, I want it to return `2.50`. Is there any way to do that without having to import a library? If there isn't a good and efficient way, then could someone point me in the right direction to where I should start reading about how to do this?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset? It's an *intersection*.

Comment: You have to use a formatted string in most programming language

Answer (score 0):

You should probably import the `decimal` module and use that:

```
import decimal

# you can use a string "2.50"
print(decimal.Decimal("2.50")) 

# or you can use a float 2.5
print(decimal.Decimal(2.5).quantize(decimal.Decimal("0.01")))


# if your float has lots of decimal places it will round up (not floor)
print(decimal.Decimal(2.556).quantize(decimal.Decimal("0.01")))
```

Here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/decimal.html

Also you can get it just as a string using "string formatting":

```
print('{:.2f}'.format(2.5))
```

Here are the docs for that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language